# How Add Image into UIAlertbox in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, uiimageview, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I would like to add Image in UIAlertbox so I add the following codes.

[image]

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Gender", message: "" , preferredStyle: .alert)

    // Create the actions
       let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Female", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
                // exit(0)
                debugPrint("Press OK")

       }
       let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Male", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
                UIAlertAction in

       }


// Add the actions
   okAction.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "female_image"), forKey: "image")
   cancelAction.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "male_image"), forKey: "image")
   alertController.addAction(okAction)
   alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
```

When I run the app, only one Image appear. What's wrong with this? 
Please anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this code its working in swift3**

```
    let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Gender", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let image = UIImage(named: "blanckstar")
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Male", style: .default)
    {
        UIAlertAction in
        // exit(0)
        debugPrint("Press Male")

    }
    action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")

    let image2 = UIImage(named: "blanckstar")
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Female", style: .default)
    {
        UIAlertAction in
        // exit(0)
        debugPrint("Press Female")

    }

    action2.setValue(image2, forKey: "image")

    alertMessage.addAction(action)
    alertMessage.addAction(action2)

    self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Happy Coading :-)**

for changing size of image you can try with fontAwesome just install pod

> pod 'FontAwesome.swift' and import FontAwesome_swift

**here is the code.....**

```
    let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Gender", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .male, textColor: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Male", style: .default)
    {
        UIAlertAction in
        // exit(0)
        debugPrint("Press Male")

    }
    action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")

    let image2 = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .female, textColor: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Female", style: .default)
    {
        UIAlertAction in
        // exit(0)
        debugPrint("Press Female")

    }

    action2.setValue(image2, forKey: "image")

    alertMessage.addAction(action)
    alertMessage.addAction(action2)

    self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hello bro @seggy, You codes work!! Thanks a lot bro. But, I would like to edit the image size. So , I added this codes. let femaleimgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30)) and femaleimgView.image = femaleimage.  Action1.setValue(femaleimgView, forKey: "image"). When I add this codes, I got error. :(

Comment: is this useful for you?

Comment: Yes bro. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello @seggy, bro could you help me to view my link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830818/how-to-check-read-more-less-should-add-in-paragraph-with-swift-3 ? I have problem with this.

Comment: sorry dude i was buzy... are you using autolayout or autoresizing ?

Comment: It's ok bro @seggy. I encounter another problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942309/disable-alert-button-when-text-field-is-null-with-swift-3 .