# Disable Alert Button when Text Field is Null with Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uitextfield, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I would like to disable the alert button when the text box is null. 
 
I put the button in Table View Cell. So, when you click that button, the alert box will pop up. 
My codes are below.

```
  func cellTapped(cell: DeviceListTableCell) {
    self.showAlertForRow(row: tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!.row)
}

    func showAlertForRow(row: Int) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "Enter Password !!!!!",
        message: "",
        preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in

    }


    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        UIAlertAction in

        let pwd = alert.textFields?[0]

        self.password = pwd?.text

        debugPrint(self.password)
        debugPrint("Press OK")


        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if(self.password == ""){

                debugPrint("Null Password!")
            }else{
                debugPrint("Not Null Password!")

            }
        })


    }

    alert.addAction(okAction)

    // Present the controller
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

}
```

and

```
protocol ButtonCellDelegate {
func cellTapped(cell: DeviceListTableCell)}
```

Could anyone help me how to disable/enable the alert button?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? It should just being a matter of commenting out the code, or removing it.

Comment: I really don't know where to put the button enable/disable code. I already tried but I got error. "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I set "okAction.isEnabled = false" before the alert.addAction(okAction) . Actually the main problem is DispatchQueue inside the function. I couldn't declare button disable code inside it. I got error.

Comment: Which part are you wanting to remove, the `OK` portion or the part in the dispatch queue?

Comment: I would like to check the text box is null or not to disable the button. That's all I want bro.

Comment: I would imagine `if (self.password != "") { alert.addAction(okAction) }` might do it...

Comment: Could you please help me to write the completed code for this part?

Comment: have you tried textField delegate methods?

Comment: How to do bro @seggy? I have no idea about that. :(

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate please read this article you can do with **func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool** and write your code in this method

Answer (score 1):

Observe the `UITextFieldTextDidChange` notification to be notified when text is changed and then enable and disable `okAction`

```
// Create an alert controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter text", preferredStyle: .alert)

    // Create an OK Button
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (_) in
      // Print "OK Tapped" to the screen when the user taps OK
      print("OK Tapped")
    }

    // Add the OK Button to the Alert Controller
    alertController.addAction(okAction)


    // Add a text field to the alert controller
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in

      // Observe the UITextFieldTextDidChange notification to be notified in the below block when text is changed
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: textField, queue: OperationQueue.main, using:
        {_ in
          // Being in this block means that something fired the UITextFieldTextDidChange notification.

          // Access the textField object from alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler:) above and get the character count of its non whitespace characters
          let textCount = textField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).count ?? 0
          let textIsNotEmpty = textCount > 0

          // If the text contains non whitespace characters, enable the OK Button
          okAction.isEnabled = textIsNotEmpty

      })
    }
```