# Creating an Image in UIAlertController

Tags: xcode, swift3

can anyone please tell me a way of adding in an image into a UIAlertController?  This is the code I have generated to produce the Alert Controller.

I believe I need to add a subview but not sure?

```
let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Congratualtions", message: "Correct answer selected, move on to next level", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
    {
        action in self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

The code works but i do not know how add an image into the action sheet...

Comment: use UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet for action sheet, image problem is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340836/swift-add-image-to-alert-view

Comment: I have followed the link provided but have an error message that says 'CGRectMake' is unavailable for swift?

Comment: oh it's swift 2: google CGRectMake to Swift 3. It should be something like that:
image.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [library (MZFormSheetPresentationController)](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetPresentationController) to create the AlertViews with Images,Buttons and lots of functions. You can design viewController as you want...

```
func formSheetControllerWithNavigationController() -> UINavigationController {
                return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "formSheetController") as! UINavigationController
}

func passDataToViewControllerAction() {

            let navigationController = self.formSheetControllerWithNavigationController()
            let formSheetController = MZFormSheetPresentationViewController(contentViewController: navigationController)
            formSheetController.presentationController?.isTransparentTouchEnabled = false
            formSheetController.presentationController?.shouldCenterVertically = true
            formSheetController.presentationController?.shouldCenterHorizontally = true
            formSheetController.presentationController?.shouldDismissOnBackgroundViewTap = true

            let yourViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as! EventDisplayViewController

            yourViewController.delegate = self



            self.present(formSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```